# Why is Python subprocess return code always 0 when running Modelsim Executable?

Tags: python, modelsim

I am using python's subprocess to start modelsim executable. In the CLI, I enter quit -f -code<-5>. This should exit modelsim with exit code -5. I've tried multiple different subprocesses such as call/run/check_call/checkoutput but they all return 0 as if it successfully ran. If modelsim is exiting with a non-zero exit code shouldn't the subprocesses be returning non-zero return code and also raising CalledProcessError?

For example:
    `python example.py` in CLI
    `status = subprocess.call([r"C:\...\...\vsim.exe", "-c", "-do"])` in python script
    `quit -f -code<non-zero integer>` in CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of quit try "exit -f -code 5".

Note Modelsim uses 1 to 231 for their own error messages so I would use a number above 256.

added: Both quit and exit seems to work OK for me, might be a version issue? I used Modelsim 2019.4 and Python 3.7.1. Here is the code I used:

Python code:

`    import sys
    import subprocess

```
def main(argv):
    status = subprocess.call([r"vsim.exe", "-c", "-do", "run.do"])
    print("vsim returned",status)    
    sys.exit(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    main(sys.argv[1:])`
```

run.do file:

`vsim top
run 1 us
quit -f -code 34`

CMD batch file:

`python callvsim.py 
@echo Python returned %ERRORLEVEL%`

And the output:

`Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
vsim returned 34
Python returned 34`

Good luck,

Hans

www.ht-lab.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried both exit and quit but they are both result in the subprocess returning 0. If Modelsim Crashes due to some error it raises the CalledProcessError. I guess exit/quit doesn't count as a failed process? Any other suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: This solution works.  status = subprocess.call() will store the return code from the called process in status, and sys.exit(status) will cause python to exit with that value.

I do not have access to vsim - you need to ensure that it actually returns a return code.

Comment: Thank you so much. It turned out to be a syntax error. I placed <> around the integer in the -code parameter. Really dumb mistake on my part but your answer helped me see that and was very insightful!